# Total download count for an item in Django

Tags: django, download, counter

I am making a website where users can download the freebies. I want to log the total downloads for each item and then display this value in my backend. Currently, I am using this function to allow users to download files from the static folders.

MODEL:

```
upload = models.FileField(upload_to ='uploads/')
downloads = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_download')
```

URL:

```
path('downloads/<int:pk>', DownloadView, name= 'download_post'),
```

VIEW:

```
def DownloadView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Item, id=request.POST.get('item_id'))
    post.downloads.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item_detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="flex items-center justify-center">
            <a href="{{item.upload.url}} " class="text-white w-full  text-center bg-black p-4 rounded-lg mt-8 hover:bg-gray-800"><button>Download this file | <span class="text-xs text-green-400">{{object.upload.size|filesizeformat}}</span></button></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could create a field on your model for it, load it within the template context and use Javascript to make an Ajax call to the DB when the download button is clicked, updating the field.

Comment: I guess it's one `upload` per model instance, so you'd add a counter to that model and increment it when you got the DL request.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to add a model field to your model, indicating the total count of downloads for each object like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    download_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, 
    null=False)
    
    def increment_download_count(self):
        """ Increments download_count of an instance by 1"""
        self.download_count += 1
```

Next, in your view, you'd have to add something along these lines to increment the download count for the current object.

```
def DownloadView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Item, id=request.POST.get('item_id'))
    post.downloads.add(request.user)
    post.increment_download_count()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('item_detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```

In your template, you could display the current count of the downloads by doing:

```
{{obj.download_count}}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. But this new model field for download will not be linked with the user model as one of the features I want in the backend is to know also which user download the item.

Comment: In this case, you should keep the logic as it is. In your Item model, you should add property to display the current count of the downloads for the item like so:
`@property
     def download_count(self):
         self.downloads.all().count()`

And then call in in your template by doing {{obj.download_count}}